# RadioButtonList toggle button with databind

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, data-binding, togglebutton, radiobuttonlist

I have a radio button list connect to a local sqldb. The table has 2 cols - `cata` and `catab`, the radiobuttonlist is binded with `cata` and it works properly. I can enter records and view records. Next I applied bootstrap toggle button css ,  when I click buttons it works like toggle button, but I don't see any change when I change from record to record.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" 
     RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" 
     SelectedValue='<%# Bind("cata") %>'>
  <asp:ListItem class="btn btn-primary" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem class="btn btn-primary" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem class="btn btn-primary" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem class="btn btn-primary active"  Value="4" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

  ![screen shot][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below javascript to make toggling between your radio buttons.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn-primary').click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('active');

            var allspan = $('#<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>').find('span');

            for (var i = 0; i < allspan.length; i++) {
                if (allspan[i] == this) {
                    $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true);
                    alert($(this).find('input[type="radio"]').val());
                }
                else {
                    $(allspan[i]).removeClass('active');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Select radio button value on Page_Load event:

**Javascript Function:**

```
function selectRadioValue(value)
    {
        var allspan = $('#<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>').find('span');

        for (var i = 0; i < allspan.length; i++) {
            var objInnerRdo = $(allspan[i]).find('input[type="radio"]');
            alert(objInnerRdo.val());
            if (objInnerRdo.val() == value)
            {
                $(allspan[i]).addClass('active');
                $(allspan[i]).find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true);
            }
            else {
                $(allspan[i]).removeClass('active');
            }
        }
    }
```

Call this function using `RegisterStartupScript` where you passing database value. For Ex. I'm passing value "**2**" on page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "Show Windows" + new Random().Next().ToString(), "selectRadioValue('2');", true);
}
```

Comment: Its still same. It behaves same way without the script. when i click a button it is active. but when i change record to next record  the radiobutton for that record doesnt become active.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehpbe3i129hknaw/Untitled.png?dl=0 i use the 1-6 links to change record

Comment: sry for the late reply. I have tried the code. I think i have given the wrong idea of what i would like to achieve. Let me explain again. My goal is to achieve the active effect based on the selected value. the value is assign to the radio list using a local db. Right now the script provided makes toggle buttons become active when i click the radiobuttonlist.

Comment: As my understanding, you want to activate radio button on page load as value coming from database??